# How to split and replace with stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to replace all `e_Mail` column where in `@tablename` with my users table (my main table).

For example:

**@tablename**

```
[name]           [eMail]         // columns 
------------------------------------------------------    
name surname     blahblah@gmail.com
```

My `users` table

```
[name]           [eMail]
----------------------------------------
name surname     blahblah@hotmail.com
```

I want to update this row's eMail column as 'blahblah@hotmail.com' in @tablename.

What will procedure do?

1- Get first value of eMail column from @tablename

2- Split value (split char: @) and get first value (for example, if value blahblah@gmail.com, get gmail.com)

3- Search first value in users table

4- When the find value in users table, (Code must find blahblah@hotmail.com) Update eMail as blahblah@hotmail.com in @tablename

5-  Get second value of eMail column from @tablename

.

.

.

So, I write a stored procedure. But this procedure is not working. Where is the problem?

```
Create Proc update_eMail
    (@tablename nvarchar(50),
     @columnname nvarchar(50))
AS
Begin 
    Declare @get_oldeMail nvarchar(100)
    Declare @get_eMail nvarchar(100)
    Declare @get_SplitValue nvarchar(100)
    Declare @get_oldSplitValue nvarchar(100)
    Declare @rowNumber int
    Declare @users_rowNumber int
    Declare @i int
    Declare @j int

    Declare @q_getRowNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)
    Declare @q_getoldeMail NVARCHAR(MAX)
    Declare @q_UpdateQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @q_getRowNumber = N'SELECT  Count(ID) 
              FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)

    EXECUTE @rowNumber = sp_executesql @q_getRowNumber

    /*Set @rowNumber = (Select Count(ID) from @tablename)*/

    Set @users_rowNumber = (Select Count(ID) from tblusers)
    Set @i = 1
    Set @j = 1

    While(@i <= @rowNumber) 
    BEGIN
        Set @q_getoldeMail = '(SELECT Lower(@columnname) FROM (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rownumber
          ,ID
          ,[Name]
          ,[Description]
          ,[Status]
          ,[AssignedTo]
          ,[AssignedToMail]
          ,[CC]
      FROM' + @tablename + '
    ) AS ar
    WHERE rownumber = @i)'

      EXECUTE @get_oldeMail = sp_executesql @q_getoldeMail

      Set @get_oldeMail = REPLACE(@get_oldeMail,'ı','i')

      WHILE LEN(@get_oldeMail) > 0 
      BEGIN
          IF CHARINDEX('@',@get_oldeMail) > 0
              SET  @get_oldSplitValue = SUBSTRING(@get_oldeMail,0,CHARINDEX('@',@get_oldeMail))
          ELSE
          BEGIN
              SET  @get_oldSplitValue = @get_oldeMail
              SET @get_oldeMail = ''
          END

          SET @get_oldeMail = REPLACE(@get_oldeMail,@get_oldSplitValue + '@' , '') 
     END

     While(@j <= @users_rowNumber) 
     BEGIN
        Set @get_eMail = (SELECT Replace(Lower(eMail),'ı','i') FROM (
          SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rownumber
          ,eMail
          FROM tblusers) AS ar
          WHERE rownumber = @j)

            WHILE LEN(@get_eMail) > 0
                BEGIN
                    IF CHARINDEX('@',@get_eMail) > 0
                        SET  @get_SplitValue = SUBSTRING(@get_eMail,0,CHARINDEX('@',@get_eMail))
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                        SET  @get_SplitValue = @get_eMail
                        SET @get_eMail = ''
                        END
                 SET @get_eMail = REPLACE(@get_eMail,@get_SplitValue + '@' , '') 
                 END
                 if(@get_splitValue = @get_oldSplitValue)
            begin
                Set @q_UpdateQuery = 'Update ar Set ' + @columnname + ' = ' + @get_email + ' Where rownumber = ' +@i
                EXECUTE  sp_executesql @q_UpdateQuery
                break
            end


        SET @j = @j+1
        END

SET @i = @i+1

END

End
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the query - in `WHILE` you have `) AS ar  WHERE rownumber = @i)'` <-- here you should move `@i` outside like `) AS ar  WHERE rownumber = ' + @i + ')'` 

and same for `@columnname`

Comment: Can you explain your question bit more with detailed examples, so that I can help you.

Comment: I explained I hope it will help you. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need to use while loop and so much code. If the two tables have matching columns then a single update statement using join and string functions like charindex, substring, replace can do the job.